# curl: google spreadsheet as .csv

Tags: curl, google-docs, google-sheets

I want to download one of my google spreadsheet using curl and save it as a .csv file. Following is the command I am using:

(curl --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=AUTH_KEY"  https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=SPREADSHEET_KEY&exportFormat=csv) > a.csv

This is downloading a file which is in pdf format. Can anybody help me in resolving this issue I am stuck with for 1 hr...

Answer (score 8):

This works: `curl 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<yourkey>/export?exportFormat=csv'`, with adequate link-sharing parameters.

Answer (score 6):

As of 6/3/2023, the steps are:

In Google Sheet, click the **Share** button, then **Get Link**.

Edit the link from:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<LONG-UGLY-CODE>/edit?usp=sharing`

To:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<LONG-UGLY-CODE>/export?exportFormat=csv`

**) Replace: **<LONG-UGLY-CODE>** with your code.*

Curl the link, `-L` will follow temporary redirects:

`curl -L 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<LONG-UGLY-CODE>/export?exportFormat=csv' -o my_sheet.csv`

Comment: if you need to get only one sheet from multi-sheet file, add &gid=nnnnnnnn to the query so it would be .../export?gid=123456789&exportFormat=csv ... Gid number is displayed in the URL if you browse your sheets.

Comment: if you need to get contents of only one cell add &range=A2 to the URL, referring to your required range.

Comment: I'm trying that and I just get a bunch of HTML with a redirect. Yet the URL works in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes.  Without them, the `&` breaks the command into a background process and a foreground process - at which point, the `exportFormat=csv`sets a variable in your bash shell named exportFormat with a value of csv; the exportFormat doesn't go to the google page, so it spits it out in the default format, pdf: Which isn't what you want.  Try:
`curl --silent -o a.csv--header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=AUTH_KEY" "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=SPREADSHEET_KEY&exportFormat=csv"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add "&hl" and quotes

ie. curl --silent --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=AUTH_KEY" "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=SPREADSHEET_KEY&hl&exportFormat=csv"