# My PostBuild Data in Github-Binder does not work. Instead of my CSV-Data, Binder shows HTML-Data in table form. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: csv, github, google-drive-api, wget, android-binder

I'd like do use a medium .CSV-file (200 MB) in a jupyter-notebook on mybinder.org, which is saved on g**gle-drive. I am following the description on https://the-turing-way.netlify.app/communication/binder/zero-to-binder.html#medium-public-files and using

```
wget -q -O
```

When I use the link to the file from g**gle-drive, I don't get the .CSV-file but an .HTML-file.
How do we get a direct URL to our .CSV-file, usable e.g. with wget?

Comment: Did you try the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393858/8508004) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783921/8508004) (maybe the 'Update as of March 2018.' one?) MyBInder instances have `curl` installed, too. Since everything has to be public to run on MyBinder, can you just share the link so those trying to help you can try?

Comment: Thank you. As my spreadsheet is larger than 200 MB I used     "wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt". And it is working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: To better highlight it is solved you may with to post an answer to your own question. Or at least add it as an 'Update' to the bottom of your post. That way you can also format the code block easily.

Answer (score 0):

As my spreadsheet is larger than 200 MB I used "wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt". And it is working fine now. Thank you for the valuable hints!